# Hamburger menu sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a menu like the one on this website: http://sterling.it/en/

I want my menu to slide from the left to the right and then to also disappear sliding to the left. Below is the code that I have written so far but it is not working properly. The menu slides the first time but then never slides again. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menuTrigger").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    /* Check if the icon does not have class active */
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      /* Do something, for example add class color-icon that changes the color of the hamburguer,
        show an alert... */
      $(".menuTrigger .hamburger").addClass("non-active");
      $("#hamburgerMenu").removeClass("active");

    } else {
      $("menuTrigger .hamburger").removeClass("non-active");
      $("#hamburgerMenu").addClass("active");
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $("#hamburgerMenu").animate({
          width: "200"
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:after {
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
}

.hamburger:before {
  top: -8px;
  left: 0%;
}

.menuTrigger:hover .hamburger:after {
  left: 0%;
}

.menuTrigger:hover .hamburger:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:before {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s, - webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2, box-shadow .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2s, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s, - webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger {
  position: relative;
  transform: transition(-50%, -50%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburgerMenuTrigger {
  height: 100vh;
}

#hamburgerMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburgerMenu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

header nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(88, 102, 110);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px;
}

header nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header nav li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

header {
  display: block;
}

header nav {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburgerMenuTrigger">
  <div class="menuTrigger" id="menuTriggerBtn">
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburgerBtn"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="hamburgerMenu">
    <nav class="hamburgereMenu-Nav">
      <ul class="hamburgerMenu-Ul">
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item  hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>01</span></a></li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>02</span></a></li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>03</span></a></li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item  hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgereMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>04</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is animate was not called in first condition and when you call it after completion of that animation you should remove and add the active class.

I have changed your code a little bit,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menuTrigger").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    /* Check if the icon does not have class active */
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      /* Do something, for example add class color-icon that changes the color of the hamburguer,
        show an alert... */
      $("#hamburgerMenu").animate({
        width: "0",
        opacity: "0" // We are reducing opacity as it looks good. :)
      }, 
      // This is the callback when the animate is completed.
      {
        complete: function() {
          $(".menuTrigger .hamburger").addClass("non-active");
          $("#hamburgerMenu").removeClass("active");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("menuTrigger .hamburger").removeClass("non-active");
      $("#hamburgerMenu").addClass("active");
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $("#hamburgerMenu").animate({
          width: "200",
          opacity: "1"
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:after {
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
}

.hamburger:before {
  top: -8px;
  left: 0%;
}

.menuTrigger:hover .hamburger:after {
  left: 0%;
}

.menuTrigger:hover .hamburger:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:before {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s, - webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2, box-shadow .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2s, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s, - webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger {
  position: relative;
  transform: transition(-50%, -50%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburgerMenuTrigger {
  height: 100vh;
}

#hamburgerMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburgerMenu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

header nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(88, 102, 110);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px;
}

header nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header nav li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

header {
  display: block;
}

header nav {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburgerMenuTrigger">
  <div class="menuTrigger" id="menuTriggerBtn">
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburgerBtn"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="hamburgerMenu">
    <nav class="hamburgereMenu-Nav">
      <ul class="hamburgerMenu-Ul">
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item  hamburgerMenu-right-li">
          <a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href="">
            <span>01</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item hamburgerMenu-right-li">
          <a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href="">
            <span>02</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item hamburgerMenu-right-li">
          <a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href="">
            <span>03</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item  hamburgerMenu-right-li">
          <a class="hamburgereMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href="">
            <span>04</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tell me if it works fine.

Comment: Yes thanks!! Also just a question can I achieve this using transform matrix?

Comment: Yes, you may achieve it through transform matrix, please refer to -  
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix 
 Also maintain different steps of animation using this and you may find the smooth one as in the following  https://codepen.io/1Marc/pen/FJbtj 
  Also you may understand it here, 
 https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Comment: How to make in on mobile to take full width?

Comment: First add the class, 
  .hamburgerMenuClass {
    width: 200px;
  } instead of applying css by id.
  Add a media query as 
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .hamburgerMenuClass {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
You may toggle the class and change the opacity using JS. I have edited the answer please check that out.

Comment: Please check in full page and mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing your active class too quickly thus setting opacity and visibilty to hide your menu. Adding an animation to the width and hiding the menu on the callback will reverse your appear-animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menuTrigger").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    /* Check if the icon does not have class active */
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      /* Do something, for example add class color-icon that changes the color of the hamburguer,
        show an alert... */
      $(".menuTrigger .hamburger").addClass("non-active");
      $("#hamburgerMenu").animate({
         width: "0"
      }, function() {
         $("#hamburgerMenu").removeClass("active");
      });
    } else {
      $("menuTrigger .hamburger").removeClass("non-active");
      $("#hamburgerMenu").addClass("active");
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $("#hamburgerMenu").animate({
          width: "200"
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 3px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:after {
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
}

.hamburger:before {
  top: -8px;
  left: 0%;
}

.menuTrigger:hover .hamburger:after {
  left: 0%;
}

.menuTrigger:hover .hamburger:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:before {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s, - webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2, box-shadow .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, background-color .3s ease-in-out .2s, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: top .2s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out .2s, - webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}

.menuTrigger {
  position: relative;
  transform: transition(-50%, -50%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburgerMenuTrigger {
  height: 100vh;
}

#hamburgerMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  padding: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#hamburgerMenu.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

header nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(88, 102, 110);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px;
}

header nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

header nav li span {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

header {
  display: block;
}

header nav {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburgerMenuTrigger">
  <div class="menuTrigger" id="menuTriggerBtn">
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburgerBtn"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="hamburgerMenu">
    <nav class="hamburgereMenu-Nav">
      <ul class="hamburgerMenu-Ul">
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item  hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>01</span></a></li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>02</span></a></li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgerMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>03</span></a></li>
        <li class="hamburgerMenu-nav-item  hamburgerMenu-right-li"><a class="hamburgereMenu-nav-link  hamburgerMenu-menu" href=""><span>04</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```